# How to configure multiple datasource in jasper report server

Tags: jasperserver

i have see the tutorial how to configure the jasper report server with the mysql,oracle and other.When i start install the jasperserver 4.5. it just show postgresql datasource. i have more than datasource connect to my report.i don't know how to configure the others datasource. How to configure all the datasource in jasper server report?.Anybody know about this?

Comment: Are you talking about the `datasource`?

Comment: yes alex. the problem is i don't know how to set more than one datasource in one files.

Answer (score 0):

Amin,

Check this How-To http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/DataSources it will guide you on the steps needed to create a new `datasource`

Comment: i have install the jasper server 4.2.1. The files have PostgreSQL for default datasource. How to add and setting another datasource such MS Sql and Db2 together with PostgreSQL in jasper server. i still confused about that.Why are they not put option for all datasource when first time install the jasper server.

Answer (score 0):

This  tool allows create datasources from de shell. 
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaspertools/?source=directory

See you.

Comment: thank you richard.but how to use the tools?.do you have the toturial for the instructions?.